# Centering an article tag

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center the content of an html `article` element.  Currently the content aligns itself with the left margin of the page. 
Here is the HTML I am using:

```
<article> 
    <h1>Sign In</h1>
    <div class="display-new">
        <form action="" method="post">
            <div class="label-field">
                <label for="email">Email: </label>
                <input type="text" name="email" />
            </div>
            <div class="label-field">
                <label for="password">Password: </label>
                <input type="password" name="password" />
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Sign In" class="submit-button"/>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="forgotten-password">
         <a href="../index.php?action=resetpassword">Forgotten your password?</a>
    </div> <!-- end forgotten-password -->
</article>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #3e3e3e;
    margin: 0 0 3rem; /* bottom = footer height */
}

footer {
    position: absolute;
    height: 3rem;
    min-width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: small;
    background-color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    /*border: 1px solid red;*/
    margin: 0 auto;
}

p, ul {
    margin: 0 0 1.5em;
    color: #838383;
}

ul {
    list-style: disc;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    top: 0;
}

h1, h2 {
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight: bold; 
    text-align: center;
}

article {
    max-width: 768px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: medium;
}

.wrapper {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    /*margin-bottom: 50px;*/
    min-height:100%;
}

.content {
    max-width: 60%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    /*padding-bottom: 5em;*/
    min-height: 100%;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    font-size: 14px;
}


/* ==== FORM classes ==== */
form {
    width: auto;
}

div.display-new {
    margin: 0 auto; 
}

form div.label-field {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 5px 0;
    text-align: left;
}

form div.label-field label, form div.label-field input {
    display: block;
}

div.forgotten-password {
    margin: 10px auto;
    font-size: smaller;
}

div.forgotten-password a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

And here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Iamnota12345/hhvbts7L/) showing the issue. I am unsure what is happening here.  There are lot of questions on StackOverflow related to centering, and a Google search identifies quite a few articles on the subject.  I have trawled through a lot of these and tried the various answers.  However, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18709086/1389927) answer probably gives a general clue to my issue.  The trouble is I don't understand what the answer is saying. Could someone please explain where my understanding is amiss please? And maybe use my issue as an illustration?

Comment: You set the text align to center, then change it to left. What's the mystery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay! So what is happening here is:

1. Your article tag IS centered, you can quickly see this by changing the background colour of your tag (I changed it to red):

[image: Article]

2. Your "display-new" div is the one that is causing the form to align left. (Again changed the background colour so you can see):

[image: display-new]

3. One option is to give display-new a set width, so that it contains the form. Then using margin: 0 auto, it will centre:

http://jsfiddle.net/hhvbts7L/8/

```
.display-new {
    width: 150px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: blue;
    text-align: left !important;
}
```

But hopefully knowing this now you can figure out your own way!

Comment: Thank you.  I had not thought to use colour to see what was going on.  Thank you also to all who have answered my question.

Comment: Make sure you select and answer so people know you don't need any more help :)

Comment: Oops! Sorry! I had meant to do that

Answer (score 0):

to center the `textboxes`.. remove the `input` on this css

```
form div.label-field label, form div.label-field input {
    display: block;
}
```

it should look like this

```
form div.label-field label, form div.label-field {
    display: block;
}
```

also center the text-alignment

```
form div.label-field {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 5px 0;
    text-align: center; //<--
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/grvwmc59/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you're looking for, you've had assigned `display:block` to your input fields, thus you should go ahead and add `margin-left:auto` and `margin-right:auto` in order to centralize input elements inside your article tag...

[Centralized](https://jsfiddle.net/Escape_Character/hhvbts7L/6/)